# Learning Django with Python 3?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

In trying to answer this question, I ran across this thread which is now close to three years old:

[Should I wait for Django to start supporting Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270192/should-i-wait-for-django-to-start-supporting-python-3)

I've spent the last year learning all I can about Python 3 and have a few Python 3 command-line applications in production. I now need to start offering a UI to other users to support other Python projects in the queue, and Django looks to me to be the best tool  for doing that within our environment. However, Django 1.5 is supporting Python 3 "experimentally" and there is no word on how soon we can expect Django 1.6 (which is claimed to fully support Python 3) to be available.

Obviously, it's going to take some months for me to do anything useful with Django, and I would be surprised if Django 1.6 isn't in stable release by the time I'm ready to deploy a production Django application, but I'm wondering what kind of frustration I'm in for in trying to learn Django with only Python 3 experience.

Thanks.

Comment: Django 1.6 is already released.https://github.com/django/django/tree/stable/1.6.x . T

Comment: You're basically asking for opinions and anecdotes, and StackOverflow is not a good forum for questions like that. You might want to consider [the mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/django-users) or [the IRC channel](irc://irc.freenode.net/django) instead.

Comment: @SrinivasReddyThatiparthy - Are you sure? It seems it's [still a beta release](https://github.com/django/django/releases), the fact that the branch is called _stable_ doesn't really mean much.

Answer (score 2):

In 2013, I still advise that if you're learning Django, use Python 2.

Many resources, including the [official tutorial for Django 1.6](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial01/) are written for Python 2.X. You may have problems using Python 3.X unless you are aware of the subtleties of porting code from Python 2 to 3.

Once you are a bit more familiar with Django, then you can try converting your project to Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what third-party packages you plan on using.

According to the documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/faq/install/#what-python-version-should-i-use-with-django):

> If you’re starting a new project, and the dependencies you plan to use work on Python 3, you should use Python 3. If they don’t, consider contributing to the porting efforts, or stick to Python 2.

If I were you, I would see what packages and dependencies you are going to use and decide from there. If you are not going to be using anything other than what you write then go for django 1.6 and python 3.

I just helped a friend through the Django tutorial using python 3 a few weeks ago and it went smoothly enough.

And remember there is an channel on irc.freenode.net for #django. The people there are really helpful make sure to check them out.